# How to re-encode MKV with H.264 using ffmpeg and VA-API?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have some problems with `ffmpeg`. I want only to decrease the video bitrate. I am using a Radeon and RadeonSI open source module for HD 8370D.

I tried the following command but if input file is `mkv` it does not work.

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i <inputfile> -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi <outfile>.mkv
```

What is the right command in order to re-encode a `mkv` to `mkv` with H.264 VA-API using `ffmpeg`?

```
metallaro1980@linux-0zob:/run/media/metallaro1980/Volume/Nuova cartella (4)> ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i "Die Hard 2 -58 minuti per morire.H264.1080p.DTS.ITA.mkv" -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi prova.mkv

    libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
    libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
    libva info: User requested driver 'radeonsi'
    libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
    libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
    libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0


    [h264_vaapi @ 0x933cc0] Encoding entrypoint not found (7 / 6).
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_vaapi))
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (dts (dca) -> opus (libopus))
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Can you please show the full, uncut command line output as well? Hit [edit] and make sure you format the log properly, by selecting it and then pressing the code (`{}`) button. Please also check the editing help.

Comment: Does it work with VA-API? (This will find out if the problem is in ffmpeg and/or your file format, or in how ffmpeg uses VA-API).